# PHP does not throw exception if mysqli is not enabled

Tags: php, mysqli, php-7

I have

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
require_once "configuration.php";
header('Content-Type: application/json');
try
{   
    $mysqli = new mysqli(MYSQL_SERVER, MYSQL_USERNAME, MYSQL_PASSWORD, MYSQL_DATABASE);
    $mysqli->set_charset("utf8");
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo json_encode(
        array(
            'msg' => $e->getMessage()
        )
    );
}
```

And if `mysqli` is not enabled then it does not catch the error:

> **Fatal error**:  Uncaught Error: Class 'mysqli' not found in C:\test\db_connect.php:8
>       Stack trace:
>       #0 C:\test\getContacts.php(2): require_once()
>       #1 {main} thrown in **C:\test\db_connect.php** on line **8**

What can I do so that it catches the error?

I have tried this one but it didn't work:

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
require_once "configuration.php";
header('Content-Type: application/json');
try
{
    if(!extension_loaded('mysqli'))
    {
        throw new Exception('mysqli is not enabled');
    }

    $mysqli = new mysqli(MYSQL_SERVER, MYSQL_USERNAME, MYSQL_PASSWORD, MYSQL_DATABASE);
    $mysqli->set_charset("utf8");
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo json_encode(
        array(
            'msg' => $e->getMessage()
        )
    );
}
```

This one does not halt, continues to execute the script.

> {"msg":"mysqli is not enabled"}
>   **Notice**:  Undefined variable: mysqli in **C:\test\getContacts.php** on line **99**
>       
>       **Fatal error**:  Uncaught Error: Call to a member function query() on null in C:\test\getContacts.php:99
>       Stack trace:
>       #0 {main}
>         thrown in **C:\test\getContacts.php** on line **99**

Comment: `mysqli` doesn't throw exceptions unless you explicitly enable them. it won't even throw one if the connection fails. You **ALWAYS** get a mysqli object back, and have to explicitly check `$mysqli->connect_error`. fatal errors are NOT exceptions. they're a php-level error that has nothing to do with objects or exceptions. they cannot be "caught", since they're not "thrown" in the first place.

Comment: `"This one does not halt, continues to execute the script"` thats because you catch the exception - it is expected behavior. If you want to stop execution after catching the exception, use `die()` or `exit`

Comment: Your error message where you thought it continued execution - that is not the same code. It is issuing an `E_NOTICE` for an undefined variable `$mysqli`, but you are _creating_ the variable there, then a fatal error on a `query()` call, but you didn't call `query()`. Some other code not posted here is responsible for the errors following the exception you threw. You need to explicitly `exit()` in your `catch {}` if you want to halt future execution.

Comment: "Uncaught **Error**" implies `catch (\Throwable $e)` when migrating to PHP 7.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's odd that it wouldn't be installed but if you're rolling your own I guess it could be omitted. I would check to see if the procedural functions exist

```
if(!function_exists('mysqli_connect')) {
    throw new Exception('mysqli is not enabled');
}
```

Comment: the php-mysql extension is not included in the default install and has to be explicitly installed or else the mysqli_* functions are not available. Of course there are exceptions if you are using a package like a lamp/wamp/mamp stack. But a simple `apt-get install php`/`yum install php` will not include it.

Answer (score 2):

As the question is tagged `php-7`: An error in php 7 can be caught but it does not inherit from `Exception` so you have to catch them differently:

```
...
} catch (Error $e) {
         ^^^^^ Not Exception
    echo json_encode(
        array(
            'msg' => $e->getMessage()
        )
    );
    // stop execution
    exit;
}
```

See the manual for more information about [error handling in php 7](http://php.net/manual/en/language.errors.php7.php).